# Ubuntu 22.10 refuses to connect to new tp-link mesh WiFi 6 system (Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE)

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, realtek-wireless, 22.10

I just updated my home network from a Verizon Actiontec MI424WR revision I router to a TP-Link AX3000 whole home mesh WiFi 6 system (Model: Deco X55) and now my HP laptop refuses to connect to my new home network after I shut down the laptop and turn it back on or after the laptop restarts. It won’t connect automatically and it won’t connect if I try to connect it manually. This issue is isolated to only this particular laptop as I have two other laptops running Ubuntu (one on 22.10 and the other on 22.04). A desktop running Windows, two iPhones, and an iPad all also work fine. My Ubuntu OS shows no updates available when clicking the Software Updater (white “A” in a gray circle).

I have tried:

- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager`
- Changing the SSID to not include special characters (alphanumeric only)
- Changing the WPA security protocol on the laptop to WPA2 and then WPA3 modes
- Changing the WPA security protocol on the mesh network to WPA2, WPA3, and then WPA2/WPA3 mixed modes
- Unchecked connect automatically in the NIC connection settings properties

The only thing that works is to turn off the NIC and then delete/forget the network’s SSID before turning off or restarting the laptop. After turning back on or restarting, I then turn the NIC back on and have to choose the SSID and type in the network’s password. As I shut my devices off when not in use, this is rather cumbersome and time-consuming considering the password is 25 characters long.

Here are some of my laptop’s stats:

```
# release #
### Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
### Description:    Ubuntu 22.10 
### Release:    22.10 
### Codename:   kinetic 

# kernel #
### Linux 5.19.0-35-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 3 18:36:56 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 

### Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7 

# lspci #
### 01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:868e]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169 

### 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ce 

# lsusb #
### Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
### Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b62a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Webcam
### Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
### Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b00a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek Bluetooth 4.2 Adapter
### Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

# rfkill #
### 0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
### 1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

# secure boot #
### SecureBoot disabled

# lsmod #
### hp_wmi                 20480  0
### sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
### platform_profile       16384  1 hp_wmi
### cfg80211             1040384  1 8821ce
### wmi_bmof               16384  0
### wmi                    32768  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof
```

Answer (score 0):

***Knock on wood***

After I tried switching my new TP-Link AX3000 whole home mesh WiFi 6 system (Model: Deco X55) out of dual band mode (2.4GHz/5GHz) and into single band mode (5GHz only), this particular laptop (Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter) no longer seems to have the problem of connecting automatically to my WiFi network upon laptop reboots/restarts and powering up from being completely shut off.